# Ability-object with multiple effects/features (game)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

I'm trying to make a class which represents an Ability of a Champion in my game. The impediment I've faced is that I don't know how to design an Ability class with multiple properties i.e. damaging, stuning, slowing. My idea was to create enum class which represents all these properties and then assign them to my abilities, for example:

```
public enum Effect {
    DAMAGE,
    SLOW,
    STUN,
    ... 
}
```

But what if I have an ability that stuns and deals damage at the same time? Should I create an Effect[] array and to deal with it somehow or should I create interface-markers like Serializable(it's the creaziest idea I've had)? Or maybe there is some technique for cases like that?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array with `Effect` objects seems fine, a list would be even better. You can even create your own wrapper class to provide additional methods calculating entity properties based on applied effects.

For example:

```
public class Effects
{
    public int calculateDamage(int baseDamage)
    {
        int damage = baseDamage;

        if (effects.contains(Effect.DAMAGE)) {
                            // some effect stacking :)
            damage *= 1.5 * Collections.frequency(effects, Effect.DAMAGE);
        }

        if (effects.contains(Effect.STUN)) {
            damage = 0;
        }

        return damage;
    }

    private final List<Effect> effects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*`Collections.frequency()` is a utility method from [Apache Commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/), which I highly recommend.*

Comment: I haven't think of it in that way) That's an interesting decision, thanks!)

Comment: Now I'm thinking that maybe instead of creating enum better solution will be to create class for every type of Effect, because every instance of Ability class incapsulates it's own properties for damage, slowing, stun+damage or slow+damage. So now I think I should create abstract class Effect with its children like Damage, Stun, Slow etc. Every Ability instance will contain a List of Effects and wrapper, which you advised, will be the only way to interact with Effects, what do you think of it?

Comment: And by the way, annotations would be a really, really bad solution for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Could you please explain me why? So I would not do such mistakes later?

Comment: Well, maybe I didn't think thoroughly before saying that :p I mean, yeah, they could be useful. Depends on whether effects are applied to classes and are constant (annotations), or dynamically assigned to objects/entities and can be changed throughout the game (instance lists).

My reaction was caused by the fact that annotations could easily be overused and/or misused if their usage is not well thought out.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a class of type Effect with all properties as Boolean attributes and then assign true or false to them as you like, and if you like to extend properties to ones you can't decide at compile time think about putting one hashmap of type HashMap in Effect class

Comment: In my class hierarchy I have abstract Ability->abstract MagicAbility->Firebolt which is an implementation. Firebolt has two effects: `Effect.DAMAGE` and `Effect.DOT` (Damage Over Time). The Effects of a `Firebolt` class are known at compile time. As @phs said I've used `EnumSet<Effect>` to set these effects into my `EnumSet` in the `Ability` class. All other children of that class just pass EnumSet value via `super(EnumSet<Effect>);` In my Firebolt class it looks like `super(EnumSet.of(Effect.DAMAGE, Effect.DOT));` All I want to know if there is more elegant way to do that?Mby via annotations?